# Permission required to view a database diagram

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions

I have recently set up SSDT for our developers to use. We enforce changes to our dev databases are made through SSDT by limiting the permissions that each developers has when connected to the server (db_datareader, db_datawriter). Within SSDT we publish our changes to the database using a deployment script which connects using a log on with elevated permissions.

My question. Given that we have gone to this length to lock down the database (to stop schema drift); is there any way that the developers can view the diagrams on this database without having to have db_owner permission? I know that each developer can create and view his or her own diagrams but i want them to be able to view all of the diagrams, which have been created by many different developers.

I don't think this will help but we are running sql server 2012

Any help will be greatly received.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186345(v=sql.110).aspx):

> - Although any user with access to a database can create a diagram, once the diagram has been created, the only users who can see it are the diagram's creator and any member of the db_owner role.
> - Ownership of diagrams can only be transferred to members of the
>     db_owner role. This is only possible if the previous owner of the
>     diagram has been removed from the database.
> - If the owner of a diagram has been removed from the database, the diagram will remain in the database until a member of the db_owner role attempts to open it. At that point the db_owner member can choose to take over ownership of the diagram.

So it seems that you won't be able to do it with lower roles like `db_datareader`.

Behind the scenes, here is what Management Studio is calling to drive the list:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_helpdiagrams
(
    @diagramname sysname = NULL,
    @owner_id int = NULL
)
WITH EXECUTE AS N'dbo'
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @user sysname
    DECLARE @dboLogin bit
    EXECUTE AS CALLER;
        SET @user = USER_NAME();
        SET @dboLogin = CONVERT(bit,IS_MEMBER('db_owner'));
    REVERT;
    SELECT
        [Database] = DB_NAME(),
        [Name] = name,
        [ID] = diagram_id,
        [Owner] = USER_NAME(principal_id),
        [OwnerID] = principal_id
    FROM
        sysdiagrams
    WHERE
        (@dboLogin = 1 OR USER_NAME(principal_id) = @user) AND
        (@diagramname IS NULL OR name = @diagramname) AND
        (@owner_id IS NULL OR principal_id = @owner_id)
    ORDER BY
        4, 5, 1
END
```

So you can see this matches the documentation.

Now a couple of workaround ideas:

- In a Logon trigger, update the `principal_id` of *all* diagrams to be the current login. This means they will have access to all diagrams until the next person logs in. Not optimal.
- Use a trigger on the `sysdiagrams` table itself (it's not *really* a system table), and whenever a diagram is created or updated, add / update a copy for each principal (with their user name appended). Not optimal either, and you could have people overwriting each other's diagrams all day long.

Here is an idea of the second workaround - all you really have to maintain here is a list of the database principals that you want to be able to access the diagrams (you'll also want to have something to clean up diagrams that have been deleted, and also some periodic maintenance that deletes diagrams for *principals* that have been deleted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.sysdiagrams_distribute
ON dbo.sysdiagrams
WITH EXECUTE AS N'dbo'
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @p TABLE(principal_id INT, name SYSNAME);

  INSERT @p SELECT principal_id, name
    FROM sys.database_principals
    -- change this list:
    WHERE name IN (N'test_blat_user', N'test_blat_user2', N'dbo');

  UPDATE d 
    SET [version] = i.version, definition = i.definition
  FROM inserted AS i
  CROSS JOIN @p AS p
  INNER JOIN dbo.sysdiagrams AS d
  ON d.name = i.name
  AND d.principal_id = p.principal_id;

  INSERT dbo.sysdiagrams(name, principal_id, version, definition)
    SELECT i.name, p.principal_id, i.version, i.definition
    FROM inserted AS i
    CROSS JOIN @p AS p
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM dbo.sysdiagrams WHERE name = i.name
      AND principal_id = p.principal_id
    );
END
GO
```

After creating a couple of diagrams, here is what an abridged version of Object Explorer looked like for these users:

[image]

Now, `dbo` will collect a whole bunch of copies of diagrams, which maybe isn't necessary, but you probably want those to be the "master" in most circumstances.

Comment: Very thorough. think i will give your last suggestion a try. thanks a lot

Comment: For anyone coming across this recently, as of SSMS 18 (preview) database diagrams are a [deprecated feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#deprecated-features)

Comment: @LowlyDBA Database Diagrams were added back into [SSMS 18.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#download-ssms-181)

Answer (score 0):

As per [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337513.aspx), an account with database owner dbo privileges is required. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186345.aspx).

So, the user who created it, or a member of the db_owner role can open diagrams.